# Prove that a set of functions has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove that a set of all functions $f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$, which are constant from a certain point, (i.e. a set $\{f\in\mathbb {N^N} \:| \: \exists l\: \exists n \in \mathbb N, \forall k>n, \: f(k)=l\} $) has the same cardinality as 
$\mathbb{N}$.

I have a big problem with this task, because I thought that if $f\in\mathbb {N^N}$, then this set (let's call it $X$) can have the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb{N}$. Because if $|\mathbb R|=|\mathbb {N^N}|$, then how it is possible that $|X|=|\mathbb{N}|$?

Comment: You are right, but since we take only **a part** of the functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, we may get a set $Y$ such that $\left|Y\right|=\left|\mathbb{N}\right|$. For example, had we took only the constant functions (i.e. $Y=\left\{f\in\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}\mid f\textrm{ is constant}\right\}$), then $\left|Y\right|=\left|\mathbb{N}\right|$ of course.

Comment: I think this problem has a stronger version.

Comment: If $S \subset T$ then $|S| \le |T|$.  Sometimes $|S| = |T|$ but sometimes $|S| < |T|$.  In this case {constant functions} $\subset$ {all functions} and |{constant functions}| < |{all functions}|....  The actual bijection $j:${constant functions}$\rightarrow \mathbb N$ is deceptively simple. If $f$ is a constant function, let $j:f\rightarrow$ the constant that $f$ maps all numbers to.  i.e.  if $f(n) =c$ is the constant function, then $j(f) = c$.  It's that simple.

Comment: An analoguous situation.  $|\mathbb N| = $ "countable".   $\mathbb J_n = \{1,2,3,......n\} \subset \mathbb N$.  But $|\mathbb J_n| = n \ne $ "countable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your set $X$ is not $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$; it's a subset. So, there is no contradiction.

For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let $X_n=\{f\in\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}\,|\,m\geqslant n\Longrightarrow f(m)=f(n)\}$. Then $X=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n$ and therefore all you need is to prove is that $|X_n|=|\mathbb{N}|$. That is easy, since $|X_n|$ is equal to the cardinal of the set of all functions from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $\mathbb N$, which is equal to the cardinal of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thank you! Everything is much clearer now, but I still can't understand one thing. $\mathbb {N^N}$ is the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to  $\mathbb N$.  $\{1,2,…,n\} \in \mathbb N $, so why the cardinal of the set of all functions from $\{1,2,…,n\}$ to $\mathbb N$ is equal to the cardinal of  $\mathbb N$?

Comment: Because the set of all functions from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $\mathbb N$ is the set $\mathbb{N}^n$ and $\bigl|\mathbb{N}^n\bigr|=|\mathbb{N}|$.